# Carregando multiplas bibliotecas com loadlibrary

Tags: c, dll

Eu tenho duas bibliotecas, `sph.dll` e `mydll.dll`, e eu tento carregá-las usando LoadLibrary conforme mostrado baixo:

```
HMODULE hlib = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
if(!hlib){ 
  printf("error");
  MessageBox(NULL, "Erro -> mydll.dll não encontrado." , "Erro IB5 Printer" , MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);}

HMODULE chlib = LoadLibrary("sph.dll");
if(!chlib){ 
  printf("error");
  MessageBox(NULL, "Erro -> sph.dll não encontrado." , "Erro IB5 Printer" , MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);}
```

O problema é que quando eu compilo surge uma mensagem de erro dizendo que `sph.dll` não foi encontrada. Quando eu chamo `sph.dll` primeiro, `mydll.dll` é que não é encontrada. Estou utilizando o ambiente DEV-C para programar.

Qual é o problema aqui?

Comment: Quando compila? Se o erro acontece no momento da compilação, é porque você esta mandando o linker linkar com estas bibliotecas e tem algo errado ou nos caminhos passados ao linker, ou na sua linha de comando. Já com o comando `LoadLibrary`, as bibliotecas são carregadas em tempo de execução, manualmente, sem a necessidade de instruções ao linker. Por favor, de mais detalhes sobre o problema.

Comment: O erro não acontece na hora da compilação, o erro acontece ao executar o programa, o mesmo informa que a dll não foi encontrada. Ambas as dlls estão no mesmo diretório, que é o mesmo diretório do executável.

Comment: Como você tem certeza que o problema é que a segunda DLL não foi encontrada? Utilize o comando `GetLastError` para identificar o que realmente aconteceu. Documentação: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Adicione o erro obtido à pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Obrigado, fiz como você pediu, o erro é 998.

Comment: Este é um código de erro. Só serve para pesquisar a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 0):

O problema do seu código não é que ele não encontra a DLL, e sim que esta ocorrendo um `segmentation fault` no momento do carregamento da DLL.

Fazendo uma busca na documentação da Microsoft pelo código de erro 998 retornado pelo comando `GetLastError`, este código indica o erro `ERROR_NOACCESS`, que é o código de erro mapeado para as falhas de segmentação do Windows.

Confira se esta utilizando versões compatíveis destas DLL; confira se suas dependências estão corretas (talvez elas dependam de outros módulos que estão causando a falha na inicialização de alguma variável utilizada no comando `DllMain`, executado no carregamento da DLL); depure as DLLs se você tiver seus códigos fontes; verifique se os arquivos não estão corrompidos (restaure de um backup, ou baixe-as novamente).

Para ajudar na determinação das dependências, utilize o programa [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/).